# css hover effect height of active list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I only want the hovered element to be affected by its height. But all row items increase in height. What can i do to increase the height of the element that is just hovered ? (If there is a solution with javascript, it will be too)

Like in this link : https://www.hizliresim.com/cou4bn6

HTML and CSS codes:

```css
.names {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.names div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.names div a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #25282e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.names div a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.names div a:hover~img {
  display: block;
}

.names div img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

Note : I've asked this question before, but the answer I approved was not exactly what I wanted (the image was hovering over the name below it, closing the text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving each of the name divs a height stops them from expanding to the size of the image, but then the names below obscure the images. As a solution I added z-index so the images display on top. Is that what you were trying to achieve?

> No, I want any name elements not to be hidden. like this link hizliresim.com/cou4bn6 –
> furkancetkin

Okay, well in the example it looked like the names were partitioned in to 3 columns, so I have done that instead. The drawback of grid is the height of the rows are linked. If you just have one row per column, and each of those is a flex container, things get a bit easier. You could likely refactor to use flex for the .names container as well to help with responsiveness.

Updated snippet:

```css
.names {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    }

    .names div div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 16px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .names div a {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #25282e;
        text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .names div a:hover {
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .names div a:hover~img {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .names div img {
        width: 40px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="names">
    <div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
        <div><a class="name" href="#">Name</a><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want any name elements not to be hidden. like this link https://www.hizliresim.com/cou4bn6

Comment: This is correct for this question but it will be 2 column with all items(from api) in mobile design. Do you have any idea for this ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make the design responsive with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));`. However, I could not find a way to have the names automatically divided in to 3 columns automatically, but still only have one row. This means you would have to count the number of results in the API call and create a component for each column with a 3rd of the results, which is awkward... I think it might be possible with the good understanding of the grid system, or simply with @media rules.